# Runtime string interpolation

Tags: mustache, ractivejs, string-interpolation

I would like to have localized text with mustache syntax.
Is any way to interpolate string using current context?

```
import Ractive from 'ractive';

var Dashboard = Ractive.components.Dashboard = Ractive.extend({
template: "<div>{{message}}</div>",
data () {
  return { name:'Mike', message: '' }
},
oncomplete() {
  this.set('message', 'hello my friend, {{name}}')
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do it now, but you can accomplish this with partials.  Render the message using a partial, and change the partial template.  The only odd thing to note is that you have to unrender / rerender the partial to make it recognize that its template has changed, hence the bool check around the partial.  I added a button to your template that calls changeMessage() when clicked to demo.

```
import Ractive from 'ractive';

Ractive.components.Dashboard = Ractive.extend({
  template: '<div>{{#render}}{{>messagePartial}}{{/}}</div> <button on-click="changeMessage()">Change message</button>',

  data() {
    return { name: 'Mike', message: '', render: true };
  },

  partials: {
    messagePartial: '{{message}}'
  },

  changeMessage() {
    this.partials.messagePartial = 'hello my friend, {{name}}';

    // force partial to re-render
    this.set('render', false);
    this.set('render', true);
  }
});
```